# Alert after modal page closed APEX 23.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle-apex

How can I alert a text when the close button (X) of modal dialog pressed ?

Note : I can't use **dialog closed** event because I want to press the **X** button of modal page not the cancel button !

Comment: Have you considered removing the "x" ?

Comment: sorry I didn't get what you said . I need the "X" button and that's the only way that user can close my modal page . according to our business rules of this task, I can't put the Cancel button for modal page and use dialog close DA. I need a listener that recognize the closing of modal page and then alert something to us

Comment: In all the projects I've worked on we've hidden the "X" button. There are 2 ways to take action on a dialog close: 1. Closing the page using the "Close Dialog" page process (usually when user saves) and 2. Cancel Dialog by clicking the "Cancel" button. The "X" doesn't have any actions bound to it. Hence my suggestion to hide it since it's causing additional complications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to capture the close dialog event. This fires for any type of close action: Dynamic action, Page process and "X" click.

Put this code in the "Execute when Page Loads" attribute of the parent page.

```
$(document).on( 'dialogclose', () => {
    console.log('Dialog Closed');
  } );
```

Currently the action is just a console call, but you could bind this to a dynamic action by triggering an event

This can also be achieved using the documented event `apexafterclosecanceldialog`. This is documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/23.2/aexjs/apex.html#.event:apexafterclosecanceldialog).

Comment: thanks for your answer ! but where should I put it exactly ? I put it in DA (event : dialog closed) and add some true actions . I see the log in console but the true actions did not work